# Display max 3 characters of number

Tags: c#, unityscript, number-formatting

I have a number at range `1` to `999`.

I want `1` through  `<10` to display a single decimal, if significant. But `10` through `999` should not display decimals at any time:

```
float[] testNums = { 2f, 3.4f, 7.59f, 22f, 37.3f, 104f, 351.7f };

string[] output = new string[testNums.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < testNums.Length; i++) {
    string strNum = testNums[i].ToString("0.#"); //"0.#" is the closest I've found
    output [i] = strNum;
}
Debug.Log(string.Join(", ", output));
```

Result: `2, 3.4, 7.6, 22, 37.7, 104, 351.7`

Desired result: `2, 3.4, 7.6, 22, 37, 104, 351`

Is there a way to achieve this only with [number formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.100).aspx), or will I have to write code for it? (e.g.:)

```
if(strNum.Length >= 4)
{
    strNum = strNum.Substring(0,3).TrimEnd('.', ',');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no number format (that i know of) that is conditional depending on the value, thus it would have to be done in code. You could of course change the format yourself in code depending on the value. For example:

```
float[] testNums = { 2f, 3.4f, 7.59f, 22f, 37.3f, 104f, 351.7f };

string[] output = new string[testNums.Length];

string lowValueFormat = "0.#";

for (int i = 0; i < testNums.Length; i++)
{
    string strNum;
    if (testNums[i] < 10)
    {
        strNum = testNums[i].ToString(lowValueFormat);
    }
    else
    {
        strNum = Math.Floor(testNums[i]).ToString();
    }
    output[i] = strNum;
}
Debug.Log(string.Join(", ", output));
```

Comment: It can be `.ToString()` instead of `.ToString(highValueFormat)`

Comment: @Sakura: Right you are, since we are using "Math.Floor()" then the high value formatting becomes redundant. Updating the answer

Comment: Haha :D Since you removed `highValueFormat`, it is redundant to define `lowValueFormat`

Comment: @Sakura: Actually it was already redundant since we used "Math.Floor()". But considering the answer suggests that we change the formatting depending on the value, it's still relevant for the answer. Because that's still what we're doing here.

May I suggest you provide an answer of your own that excludes the formatting part to clarify that changing the formatting might be redundant altogeather?

Comment: What about `(short)testNums[i]`?